# 'Failed to minify the code from this file' appearing in create-react-app when trying to build production

Tags: reactjs, webpack, minify, babeljs, create-react-app

I have created a react project using Create-React-App and now would like generate the production build. When I use `npm run build` I am getting the error:

```
Failed to minify the code from this file: 

./node_modules/pify/index.js:3
```

Create-React-App suggests the following corses of action:

> To resolve this:
>
> 1. Open an issue on the dependency's issue tracker and ask that the package be published pre-compiled.
> 2. Fork the package and publish a corrected version yourself.
> 3. If the dependency is small enough, copy it to your src/ folder and treat it as application code.

1. will take to long and seems to already be a issue (#50) raised for pify.
2. I am not sure how I would approach but I think it may be the best option
3. is not going to work because it is a dependency of a different package.

What I am looking for is come guidance on how to solve this solution before I use option 2 and rewrite a whole package.
I belive the solution would involve ejecting from create-react-app and messing with the webpack config file.

Comment: did u find any solution?